# phpmyadmin не отрабатывает, то 403, то 404, история

Tags: php, mysql, apache, phpmyadmin

Коллеги, развернул сайт на CentOS с помощью Virtualmin / Webmin, Доустановил в скриптах - **phpmyadmin**. Но дело наверное не в этом, это для полноты картины.

При обращении по ссылке: **http://---.ru/phpmyadmin/**
он выдаёт **index.php** исходным текстом в браузер, не обрабатывая.

Хотя php файл рядом, с содержимым `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` отрабатывает, пишет *PHP Version 7.0.27* и т.п.

Далее, переименовываю по ftp **phpmyadmin** на **phpmyadmin5** и переходя по ссылке **http://---.ru/phpmyadmin5/** phpmyadmin прекрасно работает! Но в тоже время и **http://---.ru/phpmyadmin/** "работает" - он так же выдаёт исходный текст **index.php**. Думал из кэша сервера/браузера где берет, перегружал апач, всё равно откуда то берет...

Далее обратно меняю название директорий **phpmyadmin5** на **phpmyadmin**, и закидываю любой файл (centos.png) в директорию **http://---.ru/phpmyadmin/centos.png**
так пишет 404 ошибку! *The requested URL /phpmyadmin/centos.png was not found on this server.* ?? Как такое возможно?

Далее обратно меняю название директорий **phpmyadmin** на **phpmyadmin5**, открываю ссылку **http://---.ru/phpmyadmin5/centos.png**
все открывает!

Т.е. проблема видимо в том, что сервер не любит именно одну директорию под названием **phpmyadmin**, и все что внутри её - не выдаёт. Вопрос в том, что это может быть, что директория **phpmyadmin** не работает, не выдаёт ни один файл *при этом названии*, а тут же, любое другое название директории, например **phpmyadmin5** работает как ни в чем не бывало, и файлы из директории и форму авторизации выдаёт.

Comment: Сервер какой nginx, apache? Нужно смотреть настройки хоста. Возможно в нем есть настройки для этой директории. Например phpmyadmin можно ставить из ap-get и он будет лежать в /usr/local например.